# Derivation of Weyl tensor

Tags: homework-and-exercises, general-relativity, differential-geometry, curvature, tensor-calculus

I want to derive the [Weyl tensor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weyl_tensor) along the lines of [this derivation](http://www.physicsforums.com/showthread.php?t=153765),
but I am unable to complete it. (I am only interested in $4$ dimension for now.)

Every contraction I perform gives either $0=R + 3 \lambda L$ or $0=0$ but not an additional equation to calculate $L$ and $\lambda$.

Does anyone know a source where I can find this derivation in detail or point me to the crucial point I am missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, drop $\lambda$, because it is useless (can be absorbed into $L$). Second, try contracting in $a$ and $c$ only. This contraction should also be zero.

Comment: Ok, then I obviously get $0=R + 3 L$, which i can write as $0=R_{bd}g^{bd} + 3 L_{bd}g^{bd}$, but how to continue now?

Comment: Don't do double contractions. You can get more information by just doing the single contraction $C_{abcd}g^{ac}=0$.

Comment: You mean, that I should stop at $0=R_{bd} + \frac{1}{2}\bigl(2 L_{bd} + g_{bd}L\bigr)$ and not contract then with $g^{bd}$?

Comment: @Michal, yes. If you now recall your $R+3L=0$, you should be able to find $L_{bd}$.